Blazor AuthenticationStateProvider problem
I have a Blazor server-side app with a need to authenticate without SQL server.
My DI in Program.cs:
builder.Services.AddScoped<AuthenticationServer>();
builder.Services.AddAuthorizationCore();
builder.Services.AddScoped<TokenServerAuthenticationStateProvider>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<AuthenticationStateProvider>(provider => provider.GetRequiredService<TokenServerAuthenticationStateProvider>());

My subclass of AuthenticationStateProvider:
public class TokenServerAuthenticationStateProvider : AuthenticationStateProvider
{
    public override async Task<AuthenticationState> GetAuthenticationStateAsync()
    {
        var token = await GetTokenAsync(); // gets the token
        var claims = new List<Claim>() { new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, Constants.WebClientUser) };
        var identity = string.IsNullOrEmpty(token) ? new ClaimsIdentity() : new ClaimsIdentity(claims);
        return new AuthenticationState(new ClaimsPrincipal(identity));            
    }

    public async Task<string> GetTokenAsync() {  // gets token from local storage  }

    public async Task SetTokenAsync(string token)
    {
        // code that stores the token in local storage here

        NotifyAuthenticationStateChanged(GetAuthenticationStateAsync());
    }
}

In my MainLayout.razor I have this split view for a login page or the app itself:
<CascadingAuthenticationState>
    <AuthorizeView Policy=@Constants.WebClientUser>
        <Authorized>               
            @Body
        </Authorized>
        <NotAuthorized>
            <Login />
        </NotAuthorized>
    </AuthorizeView>
</CascadingAuthenticationState>

In the Login.razor component I inject the AuthenticationStateProvider:
@inject TokenServerAuthenticationStateProvider tokenProvider

... in the same Login component, I have input elements for user, password and a button to login which calls a method DoLogin():
private async Task DoLogin()
{
    // authenticate user/password and get a valid token (works)
    var token = await authServer.Login(_inputUsername, _inputPassword);

    // use the custom auth state provider to set the token and call the code above
    await tokenProvider.SetTokenAsync(token);

    // reload the page
    navManager.NavigateTo("/");
}

However this doesn't work.  I am always routed back to the login page and it never deems to be authorized to view the @body.

I have tested your codes but it works well. Is your policy configured correctly?
